# Maven: Export jar with 3rd-party jars added to classpath in manifest

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I am developing a *Java maven project with Eclipse* and want to **export a jar that includes all referenced libraries**. These referenced libraries fall into one of these two categories:

1. They are *explicit (or implicit)* **dependencies in the `pom.xml`**
2. I have some **libraries not available as maven artifacts** and have put them in /lib (and added them to the build path in Eclipse)

There's the `maven-assembly-plugin`, which works fine for 1). However, I'm unable to find a maven plugin that also includes non-maven-dependencies, e.g. `"all jars in /lib"`.

Then there's the Eclipse `FatJar` plugin, which sort of works, but hasn't been updated since 2009, so it seems unmaintained. Also I prefer an export method that I can directly specify in the `pom.xml`.

Can anyone point me to a `maven` plugin or the like to export *all referenced libraries*, including those from case 2) ? That only needs to involve putting them in the jar and referencing them in the manifest's classpath.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to handle this is to include your custom libs into a local maven repository. Now you can inlcude your libraries as maven dependencies and you can export all your dependencies specified in your pom with the maven-assembly-plugin.

Here is a tutorial, how to put your libs into a local repository in maven to use it in your pom. http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/

And in your pom.xml:

```
<!-- setup jar manifest to executable with dependencies -->
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>your.main.class</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>  
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, since the project is to be maintained within a repository (git/svn, etc.), having a local maven repository within the svn/git repository seems like unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @Johannes I'm not quite sure how familiar you are with the concept of maven repositories. But since you are already using dependencies in your pom, why should it be difficult to set up a maven repository manager? The maven repo shouldn't be kept inside your version control system. For enterprise usage a company local maven repository is always preferred for availability and reproducibility.

Comment: Thanks Chasmo and SpaceTrucker, I will consider putting the dependencies in an internal maven repository.

Comment: @Chasmo thanks for this info. Actually I was looking for a way to bundle all my hadoop dependencies into a single jar (jar-with-dependencies). Your snippet above worked a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a task for [Tycho](http://eclipse.org/tycho/). It is a set of maven plugins that allows to create eclipse plugins with maven. Tycho considers manifest entries as build dependencies.

However I'm not aware of how to package all those dependencies in a single jar. This may also be conflicting with the osgi spec. But if you wish to ignore osgi you could just try the jar-with-dependencies assembly.

Comment: Thanks. So you're saying I can use Tycho also if I'm not developing an Eclipse plugin? It seems to be designed explicitly for just that.

Comment: @Johannes I have reread your question and think, that I misunderstood it. You should go with Chasmos answer.